Does sending event to Event Bridge via AWS sdk asychronous?
I am using below code in a Lambda to emit events to event bridge in AWS.
import { EventBridgeClient, PutEventsCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-eventbridge';


eventBridge = new EventBridgeClient({
      requestHandler: new NodeHttpHandler({
        requestTimeout: 5000,
        connectionTimeout: 2000,
      }),
      maxAttempts: 3,
    });

  await eventBridge.send(new PutEventsCommand(...));


The event bridge has many targets that listen on this event. My question is if the eventBridge.send async or sync request. I found the my lambda's duration is very high and when looking at the xray, it shows me all the downstream lambdas who listen on this event from the event bridge. It looks like eventBridge.send waits until all targets finish processing the event. Is it true? How can I put events to the event bridge without waiting for the targets?

The PutEvents call will complete when EventBridge receives the events. Delivery to targets is asynchronous. If you have instrumented your Lambda Function with x-ray, it will pass the trace id to EventBridge which will then propagate to the targets which will show up in your trace. So the xray trace will show the full asynchronous chain, which will be longer than the execution of the initiating function.
